# Array arguments to EQ are of different size Error

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

So I have this two column, Column A, and Column B. Column A contains a list of timestamp while Column B contains a set of time, specifically 00:00 - 06:00.

Now, what I want is in Column D, if the value of Column A matches the one on Column B, it returns a value of "0" and "1" the other way around.

I tried this formula but spreadsheet is giving me this error **"Array arguments to EQ are of different size."**

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A=B2:B8,0,1))`

[Here's a link to the sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JRMrqs1D1Ms2mfIwwDZFb0ouCBj35dJkaF2JhoTrDV4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(--NOT(ISNA(MATCH(TO_TEXT(A:A),TO_TEXT(B2:B8),0))))
```

- MATCH to check if data is present.
- ISNA IS it  Not Available?
- `--` to convert TRUE to 1

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you what's wrong. `A2:A` has 99 elements. `B2:B8` has 7. They must both have the same number of elements.

You need to change your formula to

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A=B2:B,0,1))
```

If you want blanks when a value in Column B is blank, then use

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B), NA(), IF(A2:A=B2:B,0,1))))
```